# Determine the Vectors Which Span R^4

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I understand how to determine WHETHER a set of vectors span a space, but I've been given two vectors (1,2,3,4) and (17,17,17,17) and asked to find two more vectors such that the set of all these vectors span $ \mathbb{R}^4 $.

At the moment I'm just going about with kind of a trial and error approach...is there some better way to work this out?

Hints, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I want to figure this out without a full solution.

Comment: There are methods but for this particular problem trial and error is a good one. How about starting by adding $(1,0,0,0)$?

Comment: Won't any linearly independent set of four vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ span it? So you would just need to find two more vectors that are linearly independent to the first two and each other.

Answer (score 3):

Try to complete your basis using the vectors of the standard basis: $(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0),$ etc. Pick one of them and check if the three vectors you have now are independent. If yes, great, keep the vector you chose and repeat the procedure with the three remaining vectors of the standard basis. If not, discard the vector you chose and try again with another one. Repeat until done.

Comment: I like this answer. I think the two vectors you gave should work right? I checked a matrix of these vectors for independence and got a non zero determinant, but I don't really intuitively understand how you can reach every vector in R^4 with a linear combination of these vectors.

Comment: They'll probably work, yes. If you got a non-zero determinant, you're good to go. I usually don't try to find intuition behing "ugly" vectors such as $(17,17,17,17)$, say haha. It only means that if: $$(x,y,z,t) = a(1,2,3,4) + b(17,17,17,17) + c(1,0,0,0) + d(0,1,0,0),$$ you can find unique $a,b,c$ and $d$ in terms of $x,y,z$ and $w$. It is more algebraic.

Comment: Okay great thanks, but then basically  it means that it's true that any four LI vectors in four dimensions will span R^4 right?

Comment: Precisely! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Put your two given vectors into a $4 \times 2$ row matrix $M$, and apply row operations to covert $M$ into a matrix $M'$ in which the leading nonzero entry of row $2$ is to the right of the leading nonzero entry of row $1$. The row spaces of $M$ and $M'$ are identical. It should now be obvious how to add two row vectors to $M'$ to make a basis. Your original two vectors, together with the two added row vectors, form the basis you want.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

What basis do you already know that spans $\mathbb{R}^4$?

How can you use this in combination with the vectors that you are already given to get a basis?